# Compute volume of ellipsoid using Monte Carlo methods

Tags: simulation, random

I have Mathematica code in [this link](https://pastebin.com/zRB9vEx8), and I need to compute the volume of the ellipsoid with given parameters:
$$\frac{x^2}{9} + \frac{y^2}{4} + \frac{z^2}{4} = 1$$

Can anyone give me any advice how to do it using code above?

Comment: Several examples to follow https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=monte+carlo+area

Answer (score 6):

Here a solution independent of your code which calculates the volume with MonteCarlo:

First define the region of the ellipsoid

```
elli = ImplicitRegion[x^2/9 + y^2/4 + z^2/4 <= 1, {x, y, z}]
```

Mathematica is able to calculate the volume of this region directly

```
Volume[elli]
(* 16 Pi*)
```

or alterntively with Nintegrate

```
NIntegrate[1, Element[{x, y, z}, elli], Method -> "MonteCarlo"]
(*50.660588822*)
```

Comment: Or `Integrate[1, Element[{x, y, z}, elli]]`

Comment: Thank you for advice, but it doesn't solve my problem at all :/ Computing volume of ellipsoid with MC is piece of cake. The problem rise when you need to use simulations. Could you give me a hand with applying it into my code where are three common types of MC method?

Comment: Sorry , I answered your question concerning volume of ellipsoid. Inspecting your `code` I doesn't find a part `Integrate`. It's not so easy to guess ("problem rise when you need to use simulations") what you realy ask for !

Answer (score 1):

Make $n$ random points in the cube of side $6$.  Then count how many are in the ellipse.  Divide that by $n$ and multiply by the volume of the cube.

```
n = 10000;
mylist = RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[{{-3, 3}, {-3, 3}, {-3, 3}}], 
   n];
6^3 (Count[mylist, u_ /; u[[1]]^2/9 + u[[2]]^2/4 + u[[3]]^2/4 < 1]/n)
```

(* 63153/1250 *)

[image]

Comment: You can make things computationally easier by only considering one octant, and multiplying by 8 at the end.

Comment: But then to get the same accuracy you need $8$ times the number of points.  No difference.

Answer (score 1):

In a comment, David [claims](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/219848/compute-volume-of-ellipsoid-using-monte-carlo-methods/219962?noredirect=1#comment560107_219962) that "to get the same accuracy you need 8 times the number of points."

Here's one way to prove or disprove the claim. Compare the two Monte Carlo routines that follow:

```
mcEllipsoid[{a_, b_, c_}, n_Integer?Positive] := Module[{s = 0, r, tr},
  tr = RescalingTransform[ConstantArray[{0, 1}, 3], {{0, a}, {0, b}, {0, c}}];
  Do[r = tr[RandomReal[1, {3}]]; 
     If[(#.#) &[r/{a, b, c}] <= 1, s++], {n}];
  (8 a b c) s/n]

mcEllipsoid2[{a_, b_, c_}, n_Integer?Positive] := Module[{s = 0, r, tr},
  tr = RescalingTransform[ConstantArray[{0, 1}, 3], {{-a, a}, {-b, b}, {-c, c}}];
  Do[r = tr[RandomReal[1, {3}]]; 
     If[(#.#) &[r/{a, b, c}] <= 1, s++], {n}];
  (8 a b c) s/n]
```

where the first routine only considers one octant and multiplies by $8$ at the end, while the other considers the entire ellipsoid and the cuboid enclosing it.

Some limited testing seems to indicate that for the same value of `n`, the estimates obtained by `mcEllipsoid[{3., 2, 2}, 1*^7]` are closer to the true value of the volume than the corresponding results of `mcEllipsoid2[{3., 2, 2}, 1*^7]`.

But I'll let someone else with a better computer do more stringent tests. ;)